# Sort List<T> of objects by a particular rule?

Tags: java, collections, arraylist

I have this list:

```
List<Country> countryList = new ArrayList<Country>();
```

And I want to sort the countries by their name, by using the method `getCountry()`.
How can achieve this?

UPDATE:

```
public class Country implements Comparable
@Override
public int compareTo(Object another) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}
```

Can you tell how to compare them to get it sorted by Strings?
Argentina,
Austria,
Brazil, etc.

Comment: For your update, you can use generics in `Comparable` so, instead, you should implement `Comparable<Country>` and then you will have `compareTo(Country other)`.  From there, you have two objects and can implement the comparison however.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two ways:

1. Have `Country` implement the [`java.util.Comparable`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) interface to define a **natural ordering** on your `Country` objects, i.e. make the objects themselves "know" their ordering. You can then use [`Collections.sort(List)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List%29) or just switch from your `List` to a `SortedSet` implementation like `TreeSet` (if you don't need duplicates, a `Set` drops duplicates)
2. Write a [`java.util.Comparator`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) to define an **imposed ordering** and call [`Collections.sort(List, Comparator)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator%29)  or (losing duplicates again) go for a `new TreeSet(Comparator)`.

Implementing one of these two is enough to solve your problem -- both `Comparable` and `Comparator` can be combined, though: using a `Comparator` will override any natural ordering defined by `Comparable`.

Answer (score 3):

You can call Collections.sort() providing a Comparator which compares the getCountry().

Answer (score 3):

Use the built in [sort method](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5,0/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List%29)
and make sure you implement [comparable](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5,0/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html#compareTo%28T%29) on Country